# Call function in contract deployed in etherjs

Tags: ethers.js

Here is the code I used to call `setValue` and `getValue` in contract `Hello.sol` deployed with `etherjs 5.0`:

```
  import { ContractFactory, ethers } from "ethers";

  let contract_at_address = new ethers.Contract(contract.address, abi, signer); //<<==contract.address is the deployed address. abi and signer were defined earlier.
  await contract_at_address.setValue(10); //<<setter
  let value = await contract_at_address.getValue(); //<<==value shall be 10
  console.log("value contract at address : ", value)
```

But it throws error:

```
[Sun Nov 15 2020 23:10:11.457]  WARN     Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: call revert exception (method="getValue()", errorSignature=null, errorArgs=[null], reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.0.5)
makeError@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:110810:32
throwError@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:110820:31
http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:118492:68
step@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:118174:29
fulfilled@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:118058:34
tryCallOne@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:26991:16
http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27092:27
_callTimer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30531:17
_callImmediatesPass@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30570:17
callImmediates@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30787:33
__callImmediates@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2736:35
http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2522:34
__guard@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2719:15
flushedQueue@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2521:21
flushedQueue@[native code]
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

I am following the [doc for contract](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/). The same functions are tested in `truffle/ganache` and they all work fine. What's missing here to call setter (change state) and getter (view only) functions in `ethersjs`?

UPDATE: Hello.sol

```
pragma solidity 0.7.0;

contract Hello {
    address owner;
    uint256 value;
    
    event initContract(address _owner);
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        emit initContract(owner);
    }
    
    function setValue(uint256 _value) public {
        value = _value;
    }
    
    function getValue() view public returns (uint256) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that function `getValue` is constant (`pure` or `view`)? The `errorSignature=null` error implies that `ethers.js` is trying to execute it as a transaction (rather than as an RPC).

Comment: it is view function. Updated is the `Hello.sol`.

Comment: There are 2 ways to call function in contract doc. One is hello.getValue() and another is hello.functions.getValue(). I don't quite understand the difference but both of format throw error.

Comment: The problem is that it was missing `await` in contract deployment. Contract deploy is an async operation and needs to `await contract.deployTransaxtion.wait()` before calling the functions in `contract`.

Answer (score 3):

Try out the following,

```
// Set Provider
const rpc = 'YOUR RPC';
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(rpc);

// Contract Instance
const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, provider);

// For view function
var result = await contractInstance.getValue();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: const contractInstance = await ethers.getContractAt("contracts/XYZ.sol:ContractName", contractAddress);