# How to call a function with ethers

Tags: ethers.js

I have a solidity function uri(uint256). The contract is deployed and I'm using ethers to call this contract function like so:

```
provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", [])
signer = provider.getSigner()
factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer)
contract = factory.uri(0)
```

But I get the error:

```
factory.uri is not a function
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Check out my CLI tool [create-eth-app](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/90177/call-function-in-contract-deployed-in-etherjs). Among other things, it shows how to call a contract a function with ethers.js!

Comment: I changed it and the call goes through, but it gives a call revert exception

Comment: The problem is then in the contract code.

Comment: The problem is not in the contract code. The same call works in my tests when I do it this way:
 await yieldToken.connect(signers[1]).uri(0)